# Problem with stacks and conversion from string to integer

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I'm creating a stack, and am running into some issues with a few numerical values. The issue is primarily at the end, when I am dealing with number values, not +, -, *, or / signs. I tried to check if the string was a number by checking to see if the first digit was an integer, but the code still doesn't seem to work. The sample input is 10, 2, 3, +, -, 2, *, 5, /, q. This should return the top of the stack being 2, however my code outputs that the stack's top is 0. I know there's an issue with checking if the string is a number and then pushing it to the stack, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userInput;
    stack<int> userStack;
    //Start the loop
    while(userInput!="q"){
        
        cout<<"Enter the stack elements"<<endl;
        cin>>userInput;

        if(userInput=="+"){
            
                //if + is input then pop the last two operands off the stack, add them, and push the result on the stack
                int value1 = userStack.top();//last operand of stack
                userStack.pop();
                int value2 = userStack.top();//2nd to last, needed to get this by popping value in stack
                userStack.pop();
                int myInt = value1+value2;
                userStack.push(myInt);
            
            }
            //If - is input then pop the last two operands off the stack, add them, and push the result on the stack
            else if(userInput=="-"){
              
                
                //if - is input then pop value1, pop value2, then push value2-value1 on the stack
                int value1 = userStack.top();
                userStack.pop();
                int value2 = userStack.top();
                userStack.pop();
                int myInt = value1+value2;
                userStack.push(myInt);
                
        }
            //if * is input then pop the last two opearnds off the stack, multiply them, and push the result on the stack
            else if(userInput=="*"){
               
                
                int value1 = userStack.top();
                userStack.pop();
                int value2 = userStack.top();
                userStack.pop();
                int myInt = value1*value2;
                userStack.push(myInt);
            
            }
            //if / is input, then pop value1 pop value 2 then push value 2/value 1 on the stack
            else if(userInput=="/"){
                
                    int value1 = userStack.top();
                    userStack.pop();
                    int value2 = userStack.top();
                    userStack.pop();
                    int myInt = value1/value2;
                    userStack.push(myInt);
                
            }
            else if(isdigit(userInput[0])){
            int number = stoi(userInput);
            userStack.push(number);
            }
        }
    cout<<"The stack's top is: "<<userStack.top()<<endl;
}
```

**Sample input**

```
10, 2, 3, +, -, 2, *, 5, /, q
```

Comment: The question would become much better if you clearly specify some sample inputs and corresponding outputs along with actual output you're getting and expected output.

Comment: @AnoopRana The sample input is 10, 2, 3, +, -, 2, *, 5, /, q. This should return the top of the stack being 2, however my code outputs that the stack's top is 0.

Comment: You can add the sample input and output in your question instead of here in the comments. See in your edited question i have added the sample input. Now you can add the remaining things(like sample output) and output expected etc.

Comment: Your '-' code actually adds

Comment: And your '/' code divides the topmost element by the second one, which is probably not what you intended

Comment: @Ap31 Thanks, just fixed the / portion as well

Comment: Thanks guys! The code works now. It was just a simple error with the + and / portions.